# How to specify a specific register to assign the result of a C expression in inline assembly in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

I would like to store the result of a C expression into register `a0` in a RISC-V program using GCC (for the sake of the examples below, suppose there is a `volatile int val = 42` or similar).
I am able to accomplish this with inline assembly when explicitly invoking a `mv` instruction:

```
asm ("mv a0, %0\n\t" :: "r" ((val == 0) ? 1 : val) : "a0");
```

However, the move would be unnecessary if the result would already be calculated "in" the right register.
I have tried various things using `register` variable as described in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) but failed. For example, this following gets optimized away completely:

```
register volatile int res asm("a0") = (val == 0) ? 1 : val;
```

The same with an "empty" asm statement:

```
register int res asm("a0") = (val == 0) ? 1 : val;
asm volatile ( "" /* just store */ : "=r" (res) );
```

Is there a better way to do this? Do I overlook something?

Comment: Would a simple if statement not suffice instead of a ternary? Or would it not make a difference?

Comment: I don't see why this would make a difference? It is also beside the point I think - one could replace that ternary expression with a constant one. @phuclv: I am not sure that the riscv tag is useful here at all. I stated the question more generally for a reason: I am not interested in solutions only applicable to RISC-V. AFAICT the behavior with x86 is the same.

Comment: Your "empty" asm statement attempt has an output-only operand, so the compiler assumes it overwrites the value of `res`, whose previous value is thus dead and need not be computed.  What if you make it an input operand instead?

Comment: But anyway, why are you doing this?  For all you know, the compiler may overwrite that register with the very next instruction it emits after the asm, so what was the point?  If this is part of some larger goal, perhaps you could explain it - sounds like an XY problem as it stands.

Comment: As Nate says, it's not clear why you are doing this.  Pretty sure gcc can generate decent code for all this without asm.  As a general run I'd recommend that you [don't use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  That said, how about `asm ("" :"+r" (res));`?  You only need the `volatile` if you need to calculate `res` even if you never end up using it (which seems weird).  If you don't use res, the optimizer will feel free to delete the asm unless you use volatile.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but `"=r"(res)` told the compiler that the old value of `res` was dead, so it didn't materialize it anywhere.

---

`register ... asm("regname")` local vars are [only guaranteed to do anything](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) when used as operands of an Extended `asm` statement.  If the `asm` statement itself is `asm volatile`, then it can't be optimized away even if its inputs are unused.  (Don't make the `register ... asm` variable `volatile`; that's not useful.)

So, to force the compiler to materialize the result of your expression in `a0` (e.g. for a microbenchmark where you want to partially defeat optimization for some reason, otherwise https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm):

```
   register int res asm("a0") = (val == 0) ? 1 : val;
 // then read that reg var, forcing the compiler to actually materialize it
   asm volatile("# just a comment, input picked %0" : : "r"(res));
```

This is portable to other compilers that support GNU C inline asm, including clang.

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:72,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:72,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:72,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:72,startLineNumber:3),source:%27void+foo(int+dummy,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++register+int+res+asm(%22a3%22)+%3D+(val+%3D%3D+0)+%3F+1+:+val%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22nop+%23+just+a+comment,+input+picked+%250%22+:+:+%22r%22(res))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+with+a0,+happens+to+work+only+because+a0+is+the+return-value+register.%0A//+using+a3+proves+it+doesn!%27t+work.%0Aint+bar(int+dummy,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++register+int+res+asm(%22a3%22)+%3D+(val+%3D%3D+0)+%3F+1+:+val%3B%0A++++return+res%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.20734908136483,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+RISC-V+rv32gc+gcc+10.2.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.85489785227868,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:rv32-cgcc1020,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wno-unused-parameter%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27RISC-V+rv32gc+gcc+10.2.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.14510214772132,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) (I tweaked the asm template to use a nop in front of the comment so the compiler-explorer comment filter wouldn't remove it.  An empty template string wouldn't change anything; that's only there to confirm that the compiler "knows" what register it put `res` in.)

```
void foo(int dummy, int val) {
    register int res asm("a3") = (val == 0) ? 1 : val;
    asm volatile("nop # just a comment, input picked %0" : : "r"(res));
}
```

I picked `a3` and a `void` function to make sure GCC would have no reason to happen to pick that register by chance, or even to materialize `res` at all; I'm not returning it.

```
# RISC-V gcc 10.2  -O3
foo:
        mv      a3,a1
        bne     a1,zero,.L2
        li      a3,1
.L2:
        nop # just a comment, input picked a3
  # if we had returned res, we'd have   mv  a0,a3   here 
        ret
```

**Note that this `asm` statement has no output operands and no clobbers, so the compiler knows it has no effect on any registers or memory.**

**If I'd used `"=r"(res)`**, that would tell the compiler the original value of `res` was dead, so there was no need to materialize it in that register before the asm statement executed and produced whatever the new value was going to be.  Just like if you'd written `res = rand();` or something, the previous value of `res` wouldn't need to even be calculated if nothing ever read it.

`"+r"(res)` would tell the compiler that the asm instructions read that register and then write a new value there.  You could use this to hide a constant from the optimizer, for example, so the compiler would have to assume that uses of `res` after this were a totally unknown runtime variable, even if you'd used `register int res asm("a0") = 1;`

---

### Getting it wrong, without `asm()`

```
int bar(int dummy, int val) {
    register int res asm("a3") = (val == 0) ? 1 : val;
    return res;
}
```

With `a0`, happens to "work" only because a0 is the return-value register, and we're returning `res` (to stop it optimizing away).

```
bar:                   # same computation, but without using a3
        mv      a0,a1
        bne     a1,zero,.L5
        li      a0,1
.L5:
        ret
```

And if I didn't `return res`, it would fully optimize away the calculation of an unused variable.  `volatile register int res asm("a3")` can't change that.