# assembly arm - how do I read back a register value and store that in a plain c variable

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I need to read a register (r9) into a variable.

I have this

```
 pxTopOfStack[9-4] = 0x20000000;  // Set the task's initial R9 value
```

0x20000000 is stored in R9.

how could I inline this in arm assembly? I can set r9 in assembly as follows:

```
__asm volatile ("LDR r9, = 0x20000000");
```

but how would I set a plain C variable in inline assembly?

pseudo code

```
__asm volatile ("MOV pxTopOfStack[9-4], R9"); // just trying to illustrate what I am looking for
```

Comment: This depends on the compiler. In GNU C you may use: `__asm volatile("mov %0, r9":"=r" (pxTopOfStack[9-4]));` or `__asm volatile("str r9, %0":"=m" (pxTopOfStack[9-4]))`. However, keep in mind that the C compiler may modify `r9` before the `__asm` line...

Comment: Hi @MartinRosenau, thx, found something on arm website that does the trick. Seems to be quite similar to what you suggested!

Comment: Near duplicate of [Why can't I get the value of asm registers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67864098) plus [ARM inline asm: exit system call with value read from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363860) (showing how to make an asm `"r"` or `"=r"` constraint pick a specific ARM register.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy pasted an example from [developer.arm](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0616/Using-Assembly-and-Intrinsics-in-C-or-C---Code/Writing-inline-assembly-code) and modified it. Seems to work!

```
__asm ("MOV %[result], R9"
    : [result] "=r" (pxTopOfStack[9-4])
  );
```

Comment: If you want it in an array, you might as well `str` with an `"=m"(lvalue)` memory destination operation.  If the surrounding C doesn't always want to look at it.

Comment: One day i will get good at assembly